# Soft Keyboard hides ListView elements in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-softkeyboard

I have a Fragment that contains a ListView to which I add three EditText's to and one Spinner when I select the second EditText the keyboard shows as expected but I cannot scroll the list view to the last two remaining elements in the list view while the keyboard is visible.

It's almost as though **the list view is not recognizing** that the soft-keyboard is visible the last two remaining elements are still behind the soft-keyboard.

Below is screenshots and XML of the views in question.

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

List view:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:background="@color/generic_grey">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/form_base_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Multiline View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/form_multi_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/testing"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/form_multi_edit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/form_multi_txt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/form_multi_info_btn"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/form_multi_info_btn"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/form_multi_info_btn"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/form_row_info"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/form_multi_txt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/form_select_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/testing"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/form_select_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/form_select_txt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/form_select_info_btn"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/form_select_info_btn"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/form_select_info_btn"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/form_row_info"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/form_select_txt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The view within the spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textViewSpinnerItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
style="@style/SpinnerTextViewItem"
/>
```

Complete View:
[image: Complete View]

View with Keyboard: (cannot scroll to view last two elements)
[image: Keyboard visable]

Comment: use softInputMode=adjust pan with your activity in manifest file

Comment: I already have that in my manifest

Answer (score 1):

Put the all Tags in a Realtive Layout and the Relative Layout in ScrollView. As ScrollView takes Only One Child.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/form_multi_txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/testing"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/form_multi_edit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/form_multi_txt"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/form_multi_info_btn"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/form_multi_info_btn"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/form_multi_info_btn"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/form_row_info"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/form_multi_txt"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your activity layout needs to be adjusted once soft keyboard opens and you got this not set. What you need to do is to edit your Manifest and add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to right `<activity>` tag. Here's [Handling Input Method Visibility](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html) chapter in the docs, you may want to read to see what behaviours can you set with `windowSoftInputMode`